# Redirect all .pdfs to a file via .htaccess and then display in an Iframe

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

I am trying to redirect all requests for a pdf file and then run a php script that displays in a Iframe.

At the moment it runs in a continual loop as it picks up the pdf in redirect.php

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f    
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ /control/redirect.php?file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `redirect.php` *is* loading the pdf file, which the rule matches and rewrites it back to the `redirect.php` file. So you need to check against something like the referer to make sure it's **not** the `redirect.php` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/control/redirect\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f    
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.pdf$ /control/redirect.php?file=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Not working is print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] causing the problem in redirect.php?